# Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNLocalize' could not be found, react native when importing redux state from jest testing

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, jestjs, e2e-testing

React native: Changing variable in redux state from test files in jest, after application build.
Since I cannot write the whole logic, components and props in the test file, I need to pass just one variable inside the react native app, and change its value from jest testing, so the approach is that I added a variable in redux state, and I want to change that variable while the app is running.

The problem happens in the imports before even starting tests:

**login.test.js**

```
import { by, device, element, waitFor } from 'detox';
import configureStore from '../../src/createStore';

describe('Example', () => {
  const store = configureStore();
  const { dispatch } = store;
  beforeAll(async () => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify({ store }, null, 2));
    console.log(JSON.stringify({ state: store.getState() }, null, 2));
    await device.launchApp();
  });
```

**jest.config.json**

Note: transformIgnorePatterns has react-native-localize

```
{
  "maxWorkers": 1,
  "testTimeout": 120000,
  "verbose": true,
  "rootDir": "../..",
  "reporters": ["detox/runners/jest/reporter"],
  "globalSetup": "detox/runners/jest/globalSetup",
  "globalTeardown": "detox/runners/jest/globalTeardown",
  "testEnvironment": "detox/runners/jest/testEnvironment",

  "cacheDirectory": ".jest/cache",
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "jsx", "json", "svg"],
  "modulePathIgnorePatterns": ["lib/"],
  "preset": "react-native",
  "testPathIgnorePatterns": ["\\.snap$", "<rootDir>/node_modules/"],
  "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(js|ts)x?$",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.svg$": "jest-transformer-svg"
  },
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules/(?!(@ptomasroos|axios|(jest-)?@?react-native|react-native-modal|react-navigation|react-navigation-tabs|react-navigation-redux-helpers|react-native-safari-view|react-native-linear-gradient|react-native-blur|react-native-animatable|react-native-wkwebview-reborn|react-native-safe-area-view|react-native-popup-menu|redux-persist|react-native-localize|react-native-reanimated)/)"
  ]
}
```

**Full error message:**

```
  Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNLocalize' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary.

       6 | import React from 'react';
    >  7 | import * as RNLocalize from 'react-native-localize';
         | ^

      at invariant (node_modules/invariant/invariant.js:40:15)
      at Object.getEnforcing (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TurboModule/TurboModuleRegistry.js:43:12)
      at Object.getEnforcing (node_modules/react-native-localize/src/NativeRNLocalize.ts:18:36)
      at Object.require (node_modules/react-native-localize/src/module.ts:1:1)
      at Object.require (node_modules/react-native-localize/src/index.ts:1:1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I noticed the same error after updating React Native libraries adding support for the new Fabric architecture.

Tests running with Jest are in a NodeJS (or JSDom) environment so all the native modules are unavailable. Some React Native libraries provide mocks for this situation. For all the other ones, you can provide your own mock like this:

In `jest.config.json`

```
{
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/__mocks__/jestSetup.js'],
  [your existing config]
}
```

This will run the content of `jestSetup.js` before [each test file](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array).

Then create a new `jestSetup.js` file in  `src/__mocks__`

```
/*
 * Turbo modules mocks.
 */

jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/TurboModule/TurboModuleRegistry', () => {
  const turboModuleRegistry = jest.requireActual('react-native/Libraries/TurboModule/TurboModuleRegistry');
  return {
    ...turboModuleRegistry,
    getEnforcing: (name) => {
      // List of TurboModules libraries to mock.
      const modulesToMock = ['RNLocalize'];
      if (modulesToMock.includes(name)) {
        return null;
      }
      return turboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(name);
    },
  };
});
```

Please note that this is not the only way to provide mocks with Jest but this one should work for most projects.